# Why Javascript code executes in the ko.observableArray();

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an issue, I am reading the files from google drive and listing on the page using knockout.js. 
I am using the observable array to store file data
file data includes various parameters of the file like name, size, and link etc.

***I am creating the JSON object and the push to the array.
but here is the main issue. if the file name contains the javascript code like***

```
<script>alert('i am executing');</script>
```

then it executes and show the alert message

**here are some details**

```
var file = {
  Name: <script>alert('message')</script>,
  URL: item.alternateLink,
  ServerRelativeUrl: item.alternateLink,
  modified: item.modifiedDate,
  icon: item.iconLink
};

docs.push(file);
```

is there anyone facing the same issue or have a solution to prevent unwanted script executions

Comment: It probably renders that script somewhere on the page when binding. You should escape the javascript. What is the `Name` property of `file` bound to in the html?

Comment: here  <p class="summary"><a target="_blank" data-bind="html:Name, attr:{href:URL}"></a></p>

Comment: I am in the loop    <tbody data-bind="foreach:docs">

Comment: Try binding to `text:Name` instead of `html:Name`.

Comment: my mistake, I didn't think about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [`html`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) to bind the property `Name`, any javascript code in the property will be executed by the browser. To prevent this you should use [`text`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) instead of `html` to bind the data. This will encode any HTML preventing script injection.

e.g.

```
<p class="summary">
   <a target="_blank" data-bind="text:Name, attr:{href:URL}"></a>
</p>
```